# $.getJSON doesn't return data

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, api

I'm taking a course on freecodecamp and I'm currently stuck in the weather app zipline. The API I'm calling is OpenWeatherMap. The problem for me is the $.getJson is not returning the data even doe the link is right. I placed alert outside the $.getJSON and it works fine. I'll share the source code:

***All this is done on codepen if you don't see html tag is because codepen does it by itself. CSS does this too.***

**HTML**

```
<head> 
  <title>Weather App</title>
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>Free Code Camp Zipline</h1>
  <h2>Local Weather App!</h2>
  <p id="latitude"></p>
  <p id="longitude"></p>
  <div id="weather"></div>
  <footer>
    <p>Copyright © Luis M. Alvarez 2016. All Rights Reserved</p>
  </footer> 
</body>
```

**CSS**

```
     body {
        margin: 0;
        font-family: "Georgia";
     }

    h1, h2 {
       text-align: center;
    }
    p {
     font-size: 20px;
     text-align: center;
    }
```

**Javascript**

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
    ///Geolocation

    //Find the geolocation
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
       $("#latitude").html("latitude: " + position.coords.latitude);
       $("#longitude").html("longitude: " + position.coords.longitude);  

       ///Weather API 

       //Setup for weather app    
       var key = "d160d975b9920be65fcf14313e95afb4";

       var weatherNow = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=" + position.coords.latitude + "&lon=" + position.coords.longitude + "&APPID=" + key + "&units=metric";

      //Get the weather
         //Here alert does work
      $.getJSON(weatherNow, function(data) { //Where weatherNow is on this line the alert works too example: $.getJSON(alert(weatherNow), function(data) {
         //Here the alert doesn't work
         alert(weatherNow);

     });

   });
 }; 
});
```

The comments were added here so they don't mess with the code. Please give a thorough explanation on why it doesn't work and how to make it work.

Links of the project:
https://codepen.io/Zero720/pen/RoOwaw

http://openweathermap.org/current

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Programming JavaScript will be **much** easier if you acquaint yourself with the JavaScript console in your browser. Here's the error that'll be showing up in yours:

> Mixed Content: The page at 'https://codepen.io/Zero720/pen/RoOwaw' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint 'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=42.9976979&lon=-77.50486959999999&APPID=d160d975b9920be65fcf14313e95afb4&units=metric'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

```
.
```

Comment: How do I make the request pass?

Comment: @LuisAlvarez Looks like they only allow HTTPS for paying users. https://openweathermap.desk.com/customer/portal/questions/8166727-http-to-https Your Codepen appears to be accessible as HTTP: http://codepen.io/Zero720/pen/RoOwaw

Comment: But people have done it in this page and it passes look at the example project: http://codepen.io/FreeCodeCamp/full/bELRjV

Comment: @LuisAlvarez Have you noticed that Codepen link is HTTP, not HTTPS? Remove the S from your codepen URL.

Comment: Did that and the geolocation doesn't work for some reason.

Comment: But yes searching a bit it says that I have to pay for https but for some reason my url is https and that doesn't make sense since fcc project is http. My geolocation doesn't work with http. Any workaround this?

Comment: Find a better API that supports HTTPS, I guess?

Comment: Looks that way at least on chrome because on firefox it actually works for some reason.

Comment: geolocation API support via http was removed in chrome 50:  https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/04/geolocation-on-secure-contexts-only?hl=en